# Geoserver S3 Imagemosaic sidecar files and overviews

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, amazon-s3

The geoserver documentation is a little bit off on that topic, but with this example  was able to make the imageMosaic from S3 working with this example:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/eb6c2dd0cda2e9598e3628a086cc2dd2176c9c01/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/test/resources/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/test-data/s3cogtest.zip

Due to non-starndard projection I need to use the *.prj file for each tile, but this does not seem to be working for S3.

Is there a way to load sidecar files from S3?

```
2022-07-19 06:47:51,187 DEBUG [org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.footprint] - Could not use the location attribute value to search for a sidecar file, the value was: https://s3.custom.provider/files/7565675.tif
2022-07-19 06:47:51,187 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Trying to resolve path:
```

Edit: I was able to bypass the sidecars issue with using datastore instead of shapefile.

Now the only issue is related to overviews, there are 6 overviews in every mosaic item, but the geoserver is displaying white image on first zoom levels.
Basically it should pick the closest overview or does it need an overview for each every single zoom level?

Gdalinfo on file related to overviews.

```
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (640000.000000000000000,6620000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.200000000000000,-0.200000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  640000.000, 6620000.000) ( 26d29'10.89"E, 59d41'37.63"N)
Lower Left  (  640000.000, 6615000.000) ( 26d28'59.06"E, 59d38'56.19"N)
Upper Right (  645000.000, 6620000.000) ( 26d34'30.26"E, 59d41'31.54"N)
Lower Right (  645000.000, 6615000.000) ( 26d34'18.01"E, 59d38'50.10"N)
Center      (  642500.000, 6617500.000) ( 26d31'44.56"E, 59d40'13.89"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 12500x12500, 6250x6250, 3125x3125, 1562x1562, 781x781, 390x390
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
  Overviews of mask band: 12500x12500, 6250x6250, 3125x3125, 1562x1562, 781x781,                            390x390
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 12500x12500, 6250x6250, 3125x3125, 1562x1562, 781x781, 390x390
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
  Overviews of mask band: 12500x12500, 6250x6250, 3125x3125, 1562x1562, 781x781,                            390x390
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 12500x12500, 6250x6250, 3125x3125, 1562x1562, 781x781, 390x390
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
  Overviews of mask band: 12500x12500, 6250x6250, 3125x3125, 1562x1562, 781x781,                            390x390
```

Geoserver geotools debug output, no errors visible

```
2022-07-22 05:47:59,877 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Thread:http-nio-8080-exec-6 Loading raster data for granuleDescriptor Description of a granuleDescriptor 
BBOX:       ReferencedEnvelope[640000.0 : 645000.0, 6615000.0 : 6620000.0]
file:       https://s3.custom.provider/74143.tif
gridToWorld:        PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.2], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 640000.1], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.2], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6619999.9]]
Description of level 2
Description of a granuleDescriptor level
width:      25000
height:     25000
scaleX:     1.0
scaleY:     1.0
baseToLevelTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3]]
gridToWorldTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.2], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 640000.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.2], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6620000.0]]
  
  Description of level 4
Description of a granuleDescriptor level
width:      12500
height:     12500
scaleX:     2.0
scaleY:     2.0
baseToLevelTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 2.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", -0.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 2.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", -0.0]]
gridToWorldTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.4], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 640000.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.4], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6620000.0]]

Description of level 6
Description of a granuleDescriptor level
width:      6250
height:     6250
scaleX:     4.0
scaleY:     4.0
baseToLevelTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 4.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", -0.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 4.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", -0.0]]
gridToWorldTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.8], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 640000.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.8], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6620000.0]]
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I was also able to resolve the overview issue by setting the Heterogeneous=false in the  properties file.